# Does the Left most column matters in Indexing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to know that Left most column matters in Indexing

My Table contains following fields

```
id (int Primary key)
first_name(varchar(50))
last_name varchar(50)
```

and my Index is

```
Create index ix_name_1 on name(last_name,first_name)
```

**Query**

When I am running the following query it takes the proper index

```
Select *
from name
where first_name = 'firstName' and last_name ='lastName'
```

or

```
select *
from name
where last_name = 'lastName' and first_name = 'firstName'
```

But When I am running

```
Select * from name where first_name = 'firstName'
```

it goes to a table scan.

On thing I found with this is last_name is the left most column and I tried the same for a different table and different queries by missing the left most column in where clause the same happens.

So I need to know Left most column matters in Indexing

Comment: Start with the documentation on the subject:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Comment: ... and the exact helpful quote is: "MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index".

Comment: Try creating an index, yourself, by hand. Construct a large book where you have everyone's names listed in `last_name, first_name` order. Then, first try to locate everyone with the `last_name` "smith" - it's easy, because they all appear on the same page(s) as a continuous run. Now, try to locate everyone with the `first_name` "john" - this book is not so helpful to you - you have to scan the entire book since there *could* be a "adams, john" at the start of the book and a "zorn, john" at the end, and any number of other "john"s anywhere else in between.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, left most column in index does matter, refer to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html
```

It is said that:

> The name index is an index over the last_name and first_name columns.
> The index can be used for lookups in queries that specify values in a
> known range for combinations of last_name and first_name values. It
> can also be used for queries that specify just a last_name value
> because that column is a leftmost prefix of the index (as described
> later in this section). Therefore, the name index is used for lookups
> in the following queries: ...

Comment: But when I am trying Select * from name where last_name = 'lastName' how It works?

Comment: Select * from name where last_name = 'lastName'          in this where clause also involves single column, But it properly uses the index how?

Comment: i think i made a mistake. I thought you refer to the table when saying left most column. 

refering to this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html  

it is said that the composite index will also be used in query for the left most field in the index. I will change my answer.

Comment: No, I meant left most column in indexing